# Python ftplib with accent in file name : 501 Invalid character in command

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm trying to upload a csv file including accents in the file name. Uploading the same file is working fine through Filezilla.

My code is :

```
session = ftplib.FTP('ftp.myserver.com','mylogin','mypass')
file = open(myfilepath,'rb')
session.storbinary('STOR myfolder//title_à écho âccent.txt', file)
file.close()
session.quit()
```

I'm getting the following error :

> ftplib.error_perm: 501 Invalid character in command

Any fix ?

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming from the FTP server and it is saying that it does not accept file names with non-ASCII characters.

There are FTP servers which do accept non-ASCII characters - try the server `speedtest.tele2.net` and upload to the directory `upload`.

Comment: Thanks but not sure it's coming from this as Filezilla allows me to upload the file very well.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `session.encoding= 'utf-8'` as ftplib default encoding seems to be latin-1.